# Описание формата xlsx и docx

Tags: c#, документация, office

Уважаемый хэшкод, выручай!

Не могу найти описание вышеуказанных zip-xml форматов. Несколько понимаю, они стали открытыми и можно формировать соответствующие документы без использования api ms office, что увеличит скорость экспорта данных в разы.

Поисковики меня нагло считают за новичка и предлагают научить меня чем открывать данные файлы. Ну вы же понимаете понимаете, что я и сам знаю десяток вариантов открытия этих файлов :-)

Заранее спасибо за отзывы.

ПС: не буду брезговать какими-то наработками по работе с этими файлами в исходниках.

Comment: Эти форматы _очень_ сложны. Я бы попробовал ограничиться RTF, или использовать document model MS Office.

Comment: @vladd, визуально все просто. Только жалко терять время на эксперименты и выискивания всей информации по формированию файла методом проб и ошибок. Можно гонять то через ms office данные, выискивать стили, данные в сформированных xml, прослеживать связи... Это займёт очень много времени. Мне кажется должен быть документ с описанием формата, просто найти не могу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Формат называется `Office Open XML`. Он стандартизирован `ECMA` под названием `Standard ECMA-376`. Формат реально сложный, но описан очень подробно. Один только основной описательный документ стандарта `"Office Open XML File Formats — Fundamentals
and Markup Language Reference"` занимает пять тысяч страниц. Плюс около двух тысяч страниц дополнительных материалов.

Но если энтузиазм не пропал - дерзайте, берите документацию [на сайте ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, для того чтобы создать документ xls или doc (rtf) не надо знать всю спецификацию. Достаточно только знать как описать заголовок файла, элементы которые тебе нужны (таблица, например, и пару абзацев) и служебная информация, что бы закончить файл.

1. Когда мне надо было формировать кое какие акты из базы данных (несколько сотен за один клик) Я начал работать с RTF-форматом (http://rus-notes.blogspot.ru/2012/11/rtf-rich-text-format.html
2. Когда мне почти тоже самое пришлось делать с электронными таблицами (xls) Я использовал xml-разметку документа, но сохранял его под расширением xls. Единственный минус открытии файла необходимо подтверждение. Если нужен пример такого файла на почту мне напиши я тебе скину palem[....]list[.....]ru.